# Remove properties from JSON in some cases

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like this:

```
public class SampleDto {
    private String normalProperty1;
    private String normalProperty2;
    private String normalProperty3;
    private String sensitiveProperty1;
    private String sensitiveProperty2;

    public String getNormalProperty1() {
        return normalProperty1;
    }

    public void setNormalProperty1(String normalProperty1) {
        this.normalProperty1 = normalProperty1;
    }

    public String getNormalProperty2() {
        return normalProperty2;
    }

    public void setNormalProperty2(String normalProperty2) {
        this.normalProperty2 = normalProperty2;
    }

    public String getNormalProperty3() {
        return normalProperty3;
    }

    public void setNormalProperty3(String normalProperty3) {
        this.normalProperty3 = normalProperty3;
    }

    public String getSensitiveProperty1() {
        return sensitiveProperty1;
    }

    public void setSensitiveProperty1(String sensitiveProperty1) {
        this.sensitiveProperty1 = sensitiveProperty1;
    }

    public String getSensitiveProperty2() {
        return sensitiveProperty2;
    }

    public void setSensitiveProperty2(String sensitiveProperty2) {
        this.sensitiveProperty2 = sensitiveProperty2;
    }

}
```

There are parts in the application where i need to serialize it as it is because the object is in a secure environment.

But i need to store the json in a db and store it without the sensitiveProperties, I can't just ignore the properties because they are needed in the other processes.

I was thinking to use Jackson views to solve the problem but i don't know if there is something special in Jackson where I can say, every json object that has the property "sensitiveProperty1" set it to null.

I'm using Java and Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [this site](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) covers what you're looking for pretty well.

Essentially what you'll want to do is to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "intValue" })` at the class level or `@JsonIgnore` at the field level and then Jackson should take care of the rest for you.

In your case that would look something like:

```
public class SampleDto {
    @JsonIgnore
    private String normalProperty1;
    private String normalProperty2;
    ...
```

Comment: the problem about it is that in some cases i would like to serialize the object including the sensitive ones and in some cases i would like to exclude them, and if I add the @JsonIgnore annotation it will be always ignored

Comment: In that case look at point 5 in the link I included that talks about using filters to remove certain fields during serialization